# Should I withdraw money from IRA or refinance home to pay credit card debt?

Tags: united-states, ira, debt-reduction, withdrawal

Should I refinance or withdraw from IRA to pay off 25K of credit card debt?
I am 64, self employed earning about 30K/yr.  My wife is retired. credit card debt snowballed and I now want to pay it off but cannot afford the monthly payments. Have about 300K in IRA.

Comment: Refinancing home is almost certainly the better choice. More important question is how you're going to stop borrowing and pay that down....

Comment: I hope this doesn't come off to crass but I would subtract your current age from your projected age of death. If the interest + principal paid in that time frame to your credit card is less than the total due on the credit card making normal monthly payments, then I wouldn't take out of your IRA to pay off the card.

Comment: btw, in this question http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/49595/should-i-cash-out-some-of-my-retirement-to-pay-credit-card-debt/ a guy has pretty much the same problem (25k in credit card debts and some money in deductible saving account)

Answer (score 4):

You have a standard deduction of $12,600 (Married filing joint, MFJ) plus $8000 in exemptions. A total of $20,600 off the top. In other words, just under $10,000 taxable unless you have other income you haven't disclosed. For MFJ, you are at the 10% bracket up to $18,450 in taxable income.

I would withdraw just enough to 'top off' the 10% bracket each year, whether or not you send it to pay down the card. You don't disclose the rate, but if you are able take a low interest loan to get to a sub 5% interest rate, I'd do that.